# Высота iframe по контенту

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, iframe

Друзья,перелопатил половину интернета, но рабочего решения так и не нашел. В общем, в iframe необходимо загрузить сайт и взять его высоту, пробовал плагин [iFrame Resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer), высота не менялась, стандартные 150рх, пробовал [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/) - ошибка, пробовал вот такую штуку

```js
function doIframe() {
  o = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  for (i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    if (/\bautoHeight\b/.test(o[i].className)) {
      setHeightIframe(o[i]);
      $(o[i]).load(function() {
        doIframe();
      });
    }
  }
}

function setHeightIframe(e) {
  if (e.contentDocument) {
    $(e).height(e.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 35);
  } else {
    $(e).height(e.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
}
```

Comment: Опишите подробно, и выложите ваш код

Comment: Покажите текущее нерабочее решение. Вам высоту всей загруженной страницы нужно получить?

Comment: да, решений много, но у меня не работают, главный затык в том, что нужно контент с другого домена загружать

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос: Вы хотите загрузить в *iframe* некоторый контент, но проблема в том, что Вы не знаете высоту загружаемого контента, и соответственно не знаете какую высоту *iframe*-а Вам нужно указать.

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой, когда мы разрабатывали виджеты, например для [edx](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-computer-science-mitx-6-00-1x-0).

Вы не можете выставить высоту *iframe* во "внутренностях" *iframe*. Как вариант, Вы можете посчитать высоту во "внутренностях" *iframe* и передать ее в js который подключает *iframe* в родительском окне. Для того чтобы связать js во "внутренностях" *iframe* и js в родительском окне, мы использовали библиотеку от Mozilla [jschannel](https://github.com/mozilla/jschannel).

Обратите внимание, что высота загруженного контента не всегда будет одинаковой, к изменению высоты могут привести как изменение ширины окна браузера (если у Вас респонсив страница) так и действия пользователя внутри *iframe* - все эти кейсы можно решить добавляя новые события к *jschannel*.

В случае если у Вас нет доступа к содержимому *iframe* и Вы хотите получить его высоту, к сожелению, я не знаю что Вам можно посоветовать, и вообще возможноли это.